# Yii2 reCaptcha Widget Class Not Found

Tags: yii2, widget, composer-php

So I'm trying to use the Yii2 reCaptcha widget: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-recaptcha-widget/

However, when setting the validation rule for it

```
['reCaptcha'], \himiklab\yii2\recaptcha\ReCaptchaValidator::className(), 'secret' => Yii::$app->params['reCAPTCHA.secretKey']
```

I get the error `Class 'himiklab\yii2\recaptcha\ReCaptchaValidator' not found`. I'm quite new to Composer and Yii2, so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

composer.json

```
{
    "autoload" : {
        "psr-4" : {
            "Gaiatools\\Yii\\" : "src"
        }
    },
    "name" : "gaiatools/site",
    "require" : {
        "php" : ">=7.0",
        "himiklab/yii2-recaptcha-widget" : "*"
    }
}
```

vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php

```
// autoload_psr4.php @generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'yii\\composer\\' => array($vendorDir . '/yiisoft/yii2-composer'),
    'yii\\' => array($vendorDir . '/yiisoft/yii2'),
    'himiklab\\yii2\\recaptcha\\' => array($vendorDir . '/himiklab/yii2-recaptcha-widget'),
    'cebe\\markdown\\' => array($vendorDir . '/cebe/markdown'),
    'Gaiatools\\Yii\\' => array($baseDir . '/src'),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to `require` section in `project-directory/composer.json` file

```
"himiklab/yii2-recaptcha-widget" : "*"
```

Then run in project directory command:

```
composer update
```

Comment: I already have that in my composer.json file and ran composer's update. In fact, I used the simple installation command: php composer.phar require --prefer-dist "himiklab/yii2-recaptcha-widget" "*"

Comment: Do u have this library in /vendor then?

Comment: Yes. The full path to the file is vendor/himiklab/yii2-recaptcha-widget

Comment: Please update question with code of /composer.json and /vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php file.

Comment: Code which u provided looks okay. Try those two commands: `composer clearcache` and then `composer update --optimize-autoloader`.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I'm new to Composer. I literally just started working with it last week when I started using Yii2. However, the commands above still yield the same results "Class 'himiklab\yii2\recaptcha\ReCaptchaValidator' not found"

Comment: Did U try installing any other library? If not, please try and check if it happens too

Comment: I have tried using a Font Awesome package now as well https://packagist.org/packages/rmrevin/yii2-fontawesome I get the same results when I try to use it, it tells me the class is not found: "Class 'rmrevin\yii\fontawesome\FA' not found"

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command in a terminal inside your project directory. It will be added automatically in composer.json file.

```
composer require --prefer-dist "himiklab/yii2-recaptcha-widget" "*"
```

Answer (score 0):

Often you get the error of **class not found** when the file containing the class definition is not added in current code using namespaces.

Please ensure that you have added the required namespace in file where you are setting the validation rule with following code at the top of file

use himiklab\yii2\recaptcha

Hope this will solve your problem